# How can I use a useDispatch and useSelector hook in a custom hook in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I've been trying to call the useDispatch hook and the useSelector hook in a custom hook but it always end up giving  the error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." Does this mean I cannot call it inside the custom hook?

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getImage } from '../../redux/data'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone'

export const useHandleEdit = data => {
  const file = useSelector(state => state.imageData.data); 
  const user  = useSelector(state => state.userData.data); 
  console.log("this handle edit function is working")
  const output = {
    ...data, 
    file:() => {
      if (file) {
        return file
      } else {
        return user.photourl
      }
    }
  } 
  console.log(output); 
  
}
export const useOnDrop = () => {
  const [image, setimage] = useState('')
  const [file, setfile] = useState('')
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
  const onDrop = acceptedFile => {
    const filePreview = acceptedFile.map(file =>
      Object.assign(file, {
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      })
    )
    setfile(filePreview);
    dispatch(getImage(file)); 

    const image = filePreview.map(item => item.preview)

    setimage(image)
  }

  const { getRootProps,getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: 'image/*',
    multiple: false,
    onDrop
  })

  return { getRootProps,getInputProps, image, file }
}
```

Comment: You can use your custom hooks only with in react components (try to call them inside react components)

Comment: I did just that

Comment: Which line throws this error?